# How to Center div AND place at bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

In all the posts I've been able to find a deal with either centering a div inside another div or putting a div at the bottom of another div, and the advice has been great but I haven't been able to find anything to do both.

My code is:

```
<body style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-image:url(header.png);position:relative;">
    <div>
      <div style="height:75px; width:950px; background-image:url(formtop.png); bottom:0; position: absolute; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <div style="float:left; position:relative; left:30px; top:15px">
          <img src="logo.png" width="88" height="38">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:15px">
          <h1>Product Form</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

All I want to do is to put the `formtop.png` div at the bottom and center of the containing div. I can do one or the other but I can't do both. If I change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` then the image centers itself but its too high. When I change it back to absolute then it sits nicely at the bottom of its containing div but in IE it's way off the right and in firefox it's at the left side of the page.

Any advice?

Comment: Could you fix your HTML code?  It's currently malformed, and it's hard to unambiguously figure out how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Also, it would be much easier to parse if you posted your CSS as a separate stylesheet instead of using inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the formtop.png `<div>` to 100% width and centering the background image using CSS:

```
<!-- div with the formtop.png background -->
<div style="
   height:75px; 
   width:100%; 
   background:url(formtop.png) no-repeat 50% 0; 
   bottom:0; 
   position: absolute;">
```

As an aside, if you move all your inline styles into a .css file, your code will be a lot easier to work with and maintain:

```
<div class="formTop">

.formTop {    
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;    

    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;

    /* Set the background image to centered in this element */
    background: url(formtop.png) no-repeat 50% 0;      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly what I needed. Looks great in IE and Firefox. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `left:0; right:0;` trick for absolutely positioned elements? It does not work for IE7 nor IE6, but it does for the rest of the browsers and later versions.

This is an example http://jsfiddle.net/6w6VR/

Comment: Hi, nice method...! I don't understand no upvotes until now... Anyway, that is cool. Can I ask you how position can affect margins behaviour?

Comment: If you want to center the div and *move it* from the center, you won't be able using this trick, because you're forced to use `margin-right` and `margin-left` as `auto`. But you still can nest a `div` inside and play with its margin, position, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid html elements that are only used for style, because you might wish to change your style later.

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/), which uses the `:after` pseudoclass:

```
div {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(header.png);
}

div:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Wiktionary-ico-de.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0px;
}
```

You can set your *header.png* as background for `div`.